# Updater-notifier-common wont install on 16.10 OVH

Tags: dpkg, 16.10, update-notifier

I've recently done a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety onto my OVH server but it seemed to come missing a large amount of basic things such as most of my system tools, no mousepad, nano, curl, gedit .... the list goes on.
I've managed to get a fair few things on now but I've hit a major bump in the road in the form of `update-notifier-common`. That and two other dependencies won't install or at least the other two don't seem to before this one.

I've tried quite a few things around including very vaguely a `dpkg-divert` thing but not even sure I did that right so you guys are my last hope. Below is the error I keep getting when doing `apt-get -f install`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  update-notifier-common
The following NEW packages will be installed
  update-notifier-common
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 17 not to upgrade.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/161 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,411 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 103151 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../update-notifier-common_3.175.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking update-notifier-common (3.175.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/update-notifier-common_3.175.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic', which is also in package apt-config-auto-update 2.0.0-1ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/update-notifier-common_3.175.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems to be stopping me installing nearly anything else I'd want/need. Any help or suggestions would be massively appreciated.

Comment: You could try to remove `apt-config-auto-update` via `apt-get purge apt-config-auto-update`. Not sure how many dependencies this package has, but it seems that both packages provide the same file which is preventing you from installing `update-notifier-common`.

Comment: Which edition of Ubuntu did you install? Did you grab Ubuntu Server by any chance? Those come without a graphical user interface whatsoever by default. What's the output of `apt-cache policy update-notifier-common apt-config-auto-update`?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a necro-post here, but if you remove apt-config-auto-update via

```
dpkg --remove apt-config-auto-update
```

then you can do your apt-get -f install.
(apt-get didn't remove it for me.)